# Free filesystem drivers for ext3 on OS X Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-leopard, ext3

I have an external drive that holds an ext3 partition, which is shared on the network via NFS. Problem is, I can't see this drive on my MacBook after I mount this via Directory Utility.

Does anyone have a working setup of an ext3 partition mounted on OS X Leopard (10.5) (even as an ext2 partition) ? Are there any free packages to add ext3 filesystem support to OS X Leopard ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is this discussion at InsanelyMac -- [**Mount ext3 partitions in OS X**](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=34227)
Another discussion at MacRumors -- [**Anybody understand how ext2fsx works?**](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=557973)

1. Get `ext2fsx` [from Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsx/)

   - Mount as `ext2`

   mount -t ext2 /dev/disk0s3 /Volumes/linux1

**Update**: Check reference by `Mikko` in the other answer -- [fuse-ext2](http://alperakcan.org/?open=projects&project=fuse-ext2)

Comment: ext2fsx cannot be installed on a MacBook running OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Comment: This has been superceded by fuse-ext2 project (see below)

Answer (score 5):

Use [FUSE for OS X](http://osxfuse.github.com/) and the [fuse-ext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/) module to read and write ext2 and ext3 systems.