# Linux File Format on OSX

Tags: linux, macos, osx-snow-leopard

How would I read Linux formatted file systems (EX3 or EX4) on OXS (Snow Leopard)?

Comment: Similar questions at http://superuser.com/questions/17205/free-filesystem-drivers-for-ext3-on-os-x-leopard and http://superuser.com/questions/17205/free-filesystem-drivers-for-ext3-on-os-x-leopard

Answer (score 0):

Download and install MacFUSE. That adds tools that can read (and write) file systems that aren't Mac native.