# How to mount an encrypted ext3 filesystem under OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, encryption, ext3, luks

I know [how to mount an ext3 filesystem in OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/17205/free-filesystem-drivers-for-ext3-on-os-x-leopard) with MacFUSE and fuse-ext2. But how can I mount an encrypted ext3 volume?

I have Mac OS X 10.6 "Snow Leopard" running.

Comment: Which encryption?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: AES 128 with a SHA256 hashing.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't matter. The mechanism does. TrueCrypt? LUKS? Something else?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: LUKS.

Comment: See also: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92312/can-i-decrypt-a-dm-crypt-filesystem-on-os-x/132360

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/604554/encrypted-filesystem-shared-with-mac-os-x

Comment: Looks like if you want portability then a better option is veracrypt/truecrypt/zulucrypt which are compatible with each other and have clients for linux, mac, windows, ios, android, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no way to mount unencrypted LVM volumes in OS X, much less LUKS-encrypted volumes.

Comment: This was posted in April 2010. Have any new solutions appeared in the last 4 years?

Comment: Hello from 2023! There is a solution now: https://superuser.com/a/1807058/1157555

Answer (score 21):

One really slow and "stupid" way to do this is to install a tiny linux distro in a virtual machine, let that work as a interface against the disk by sharing a folder with the host(OS X). It is completely overkill, but it will work.

Comment: So it seems the trivial answer is that I cannot mount an encrypted volume in OS X but your solution is a good workaround for my problem, though. Thanks.

Comment: It's really a compromise. LUKS is secure because it runs in the kernel space. But when doing encryption in a virtual machine, clear passphrase would be store in the user space of host machine. Some virtual machine software even maps vm memory into non-privileged user's process memory or files when suspending.

Answer (score 1):

**2023 Answer**

You can use [Linsk](https://github.com/AlexSSD7/linsk). It is a utility that wraps around a lightweight Alpine Linux VM, allowing you to mount any Linux file system (including **LUKS**) that is then exposed to the host machine through a network file share.

**Disclosure**: I'm the author.

Answer (score 0):

You could try OSXCrypt which is "test-software" or something like that...

It might wreck your system since it's still underdevelopment. Not sure if you want that. 
I believe that it's supposed to let you access LUKS encrypted volumes under OSX. According to their website everything is a no-guarantee basis so if you have important or valuable files on the disk it's better off not trying it.
Link [here](http://www.osxcrypt.org/).

Comment: It supports TrueCrypt. They want to let the community handle LUKS support.

Comment: Oh. I see. I was wrong then. Well... what now? delete the answer?