# How to mount USB disk with LVM/LUKS crypted volumes on a Mac?

Tags: macbook, lvm, luks, device-mapper

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to mount an encrypted ext3 filesystem under OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/110032/how-to-mount-an-encrypted-ext3-filesystem-under-os-x)

I have a USB disk that I've partitioned with LVM and encrypted some of the volumes with LUKS.

This is all Linux/Device Mapper stuff, so how can I use it on a Mac?