# USB with Linux Partition convert for Mac?

Tags: linux, mac, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB drive that I somehow managed to partition it as "Linux" (according to Mac) as I did format and copy the files on a "Linux" OS.

Is there anyway for me to convert it to be readable in Mac? or Windows?

```
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *8.0 GB     disk1
   1:                      Linux                         8.0 GB     disk1s1
```

Comment: You can't just "convert" a partition without losing the data on it. It'd be easier to install appropriate drivers for Windows or OS X to read the Linux filesystem. See: [Mount ext3fs in Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/8298/mount-ext3fs-in-windows/8306#8306) and [Free filesystem drivers for ext3 on OS X Leopard](http://superuser.com/questions/17205/free-filesystem-drivers-for-ext3-on-os-x-leopard)

Comment: @slhck I'd upvote that if it was an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you reformat the USB drive as FAT32, then it should be readable in Mac, Windows, and Linunx OSs.
If you're using Ubuntu this can be done via the disk manager utility.
Of course, however, you will lose everything on the drive.